# OnClick Return wrong position and data to filtered text on listvew

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, oncreateoptionsmenu

Respectable Gurus
Bellow code return wrong position and data by clicking on listview filtered Item of `ArrayAdapter`, Any Suggestion will by highly appreciated.
`Listview` can be easily and perfectly filtered by bellow code by on setOnItemClickListener` it returns Wrong position.
Any Suggestion will by highly appreciated.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

---------Variables------
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);        
    Intent i = getIntent();
    name2=i.getStringExtra("chiled");
    postion = i.getIntExtra("id",0);
    chiled= i.getStringExtra("name").replace(" ", "_");
    //-------------------------Action Bar-------
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (mActionBar != null) {
    ----Action BarCode---------
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this,
            R.layout.listview_item,R.id.text);
    //################# FireBaseStarts
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading List...");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference(chiled);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("order");
    queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long b = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            imageUrls = new String[(int) b];
            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ddataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Object value = ddataSnapshot.getValue();
                adapter.add(((Map) value).get("name").toString());
                imageUrls[i] = ((Map) value).get("url").toString();
                i++;
            }
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("Database Error is: ", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", adapter.getItem(position));
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
//---------------Search Starts
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    final MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.inputSearch);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Naghma...");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
//    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: Is the position wrong with respect to the `ListView` entries or the `Firebase` entries? It is possible that the relative positions of data elements are not the same in the two.

Comment: post your `Adapter` Code

Comment: Position is wrond with respect to thle listview entries. And it is array adapter not custom adapter

Comment: If you are select an item after filter then you will get the position of filtered list not the original list.

Comment: No Sir, I get the original position while  I select an item after filter list

Comment: If get the original position then what's problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

try `adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();` like below

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();
        Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this,
                SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", name);
        i.putExtra("id", position);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

onChange call   `dataAdapterName.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long b = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            imageUrls = new String[(int) b];
            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ddataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Object value = ddataSnapshot.getValue();
                adapter.add(((Map) value).get("name").toString());
                imageUrls[i] = ((Map) value).get("url").toString();
                i++;
            }
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // change here
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try your given code result is same as describe above, Means OnClick position return with Old listview Positions and data while it should be return with respect to Searched/Filtered Position and data. Which is I am going to filter with onCreateOptionsMenu Ovrride method

Comment: I updated the code with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but get same result. Please Help , I am stuck here for more then a weak.